# Change the width of a character to match the size of a TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, text, fonts, textfield, text-formatting

I've read tons of posts about setting the size of a `TextField` to match the width of the string containing it. I'm looking for a way to do it the other way around. The `TextField` in my application should have a fixed with and I want to squeeze the text in it by changing the width of a single character.

The solution I'm working width now decreases the size of the font until it fits into the `TextField`, but I want to squeeze the text (so decreasing just width, not height) until it fits in the `TextField`. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to scale font on a single axis.

The only thing i could think of is to bake the text field and scale the resulting bitmap:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "bitmap text";
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(80, 20);
myBitmapData.draw(tf);
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
this.addChild(bmp);
```

[Source](http://coldconstructs.com/2008/06/scaling-dynamic-text-in-as3/)

Comment: there was a little more to it then the source you posted, but it definitely pointed me the right direction, thanks!